# How to access JSON data from a returned string from WCF

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, wcf, parsing

I have a WCF service that returns a simple string with OperationContract as follows:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json]
```

I return the string `"error2"` and I also tried to parse it before hand like so:

```
return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { result = "error2" });
```

In the first try (without parsing on the server), when I read in the client JSON.parse(e.response) and access result, I get `error2` instead of an `"error2"` string.

I tried both options and still can't figure out how to properly return a string from WCF and read the result ("error2") as string on the client side in Javascript.

I think that I either doing something wrong on the client, server or both.

What I tried:

```
var json = JSON.parse(e.response) 
alert(json.result) <-- give me error2 instead of a string
```

Also tried this:

Server (WCF)

```
 return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { result = "\"error2\"" });
```

On client

```
var json = JSON.parse(e.response);
alert(json.result);
alert(e.response);
alert((e.response).result);
```

Get:  `undefined`,  `"{\"result":\"\\\"error\\\"\"}"`, `undefined` - respectively.

**Try 3**

On Server

```
return "error2";
```

On Client

```
alert(e.response); <-- "error2"
```

However, when I try to compare the following:

```
alert(e.response === "error2")
```

I get `false` instead of `true`. I double chechked the result using PostMan chrome plugin, and the returned value is indeed "error 2".

**Update:** I think there there might be issue with the unicode of the text. I tried comparing two "error" strings one that I get from the WCF and one from regular typing and get different results when encoding them in Base 64. Is there a way to make WCF response in utf-8 so both strings can be equal, and therefore the use of the JSON data access attribute name will work?

Is there an option to control the encoding of the WCF output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping your quotes

```
result = "\"error2\""
```

Comment: Not working, I update the question with the results of the alerts according to what you told me to do.